# using CTE while declaring variables in SQL

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I have two decraed variables and I am trying to set the values from the result of my CTE,

```
 declare @Total_new_claims_received int
 declare @Total_Claims_Processed int
```

End solution I'm looking for is being able to set both declared values from CTE results:

```
select @Total_new_claims_received = count(id) 
from cte 
where benefit_code_id not in ('739')



select @Total_Claims_Processed = count(id)
from cte2
where benefit_code_id  not in ('739')
```

Current Code:

```
 declare @Total_new_claims_received int
 declare @Total_Claims_Processed int

 with cte (ID, Date)
   as (

   select c.id, c.date
from axiscore.dbo.claim c with (nolock)
    inner join claim_line cl on c.Claim_ID = cl.Claim_ID and cl.Linenum = 1
    left join axiscore.dbo.member_policy mp with (nolock) on c.Member_Policy_ID = mp.Member_Policy_ID
    left join axiscore.dbo.policy p with (nolock) on mp.policy_id = p.policy_id
    inner join axiscore.dbo.Claim_Status s with (nolock) on c.Claim_Status_ID = s.Claim_Status_ID
    left outer join axiscore.dbo.Claim_Reason_Type r with (nolock) on c.Claim_Reason_Type_ID = r.Claim_Reason_Type_ID
where 
c.Updated_Date between '10-1-2019' and '10-31-2019'
and p.Payor_ID = 8
and (c.Claim_Status_ID <> 8)),



   cte2 (ID, Date)
   as 
   (
   select c.id, c.date
from axiscore.dbo.claim c with (nolock)
    inner join claim_line cl on c.Claim_ID = cl.Claim_ID and cl.Linenum = 1
    left join axiscore.dbo.member_policy mp with (nolock) on c.Member_Policy_ID = mp.Member_Policy_ID
    left join axiscore.dbo.policy p with (nolock) on mp.policy_id = p.policy_id
    inner join axiscore.dbo.Claim_Status s with (nolock) on c.Claim_Status_ID = s.Claim_Status_ID
    left outer join axiscore.dbo.Claim_Reason_Type r with (nolock) on c.Claim_Reason_Type_ID = r.Claim_Reason_Type_ID
where 
c.Updated_Date between '10-1-2019' and '10-31-2019'
and p.Payor_ID = 8
and (c.Claim_Status_ID in (7,6))                                                
and (c.Claim_Reason_Type_ID not in (136,137))) 




select @Total_new_claims_received = count(id)
from cte
where benefit_code_id  not in ('739')



select @Total_Claims_Processed = count(id)
from cte2
where benefit_code_id  not in ('739')
```

Currently,

it's only setting the value for Total_new_claims_received. It errors out on the second select when I'm setting the value for Total_Claims_Processed. The error is 'invalid object name 'cte2'.

I'm using CTE instead of temp tables becuase I'm calling this proc in a SSIS package. SSIS package doesn't do well with Temp tables. Any other ideas welcome as well.

thanks for your time!

Comment: Please post your code so we might identify your possible issues.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? SQL (the query language) does not support variables at all

Comment: just added code. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> A CTE must be followed by a **single** SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or
>   DELETE statement that references some or all the CTE columns

So define each of your CTEs before each of the select statements that uses it:

```
 declare @Total_new_claims_received int
 declare @Total_Claims_Processed int

with cte (ID, Date) as (
    select c.id, c.date
    from axiscore.dbo.claim c with (nolock)
    inner join claim_line cl on c.Claim_ID = cl.Claim_ID and cl.Linenum = 1
    left join axiscore.dbo.member_policy mp with (nolock) on c.Member_Policy_ID = mp.Member_Policy_ID
    left join axiscore.dbo.policy p with (nolock) on mp.policy_id = p.policy_id
    inner join axiscore.dbo.Claim_Status s with (nolock) on c.Claim_Status_ID = s.Claim_Status_ID
    left outer join axiscore.dbo.Claim_Reason_Type r with (nolock) on c.Claim_Reason_Type_ID = r.Claim_Reason_Type_ID
    where 
      c.Updated_Date between '10-1-2019' and '10-31-2019'
      and p.Payor_ID = 8
      and (c.Claim_Status_ID <> 8)
    )
select @Total_new_claims_received = count(id)
from cte
where benefit_code_id  not in ('739');

with cte2 (ID, Date) as (
    select c.id, c.date
    from axiscore.dbo.claim c with (nolock)
    inner join claim_line cl on c.Claim_ID = cl.Claim_ID and cl.Linenum = 1
    left join axiscore.dbo.member_policy mp with (nolock) on c.Member_Policy_ID = mp.Member_Policy_ID
    left join axiscore.dbo.policy p with (nolock) on mp.policy_id = p.policy_id
    inner join axiscore.dbo.Claim_Status s with (nolock) on c.Claim_Status_ID = s.Claim_Status_ID
    left outer join axiscore.dbo.Claim_Reason_Type r with (nolock) on c.Claim_Reason_Type_ID = r.Claim_Reason_Type_ID
    where 
      c.Updated_Date between '10-1-2019' and '10-31-2019'
      and p.Payor_ID = 8
      and (c.Claim_Status_ID in (7,6))                                                
      and (c.Claim_Reason_Type_ID not in (136,137))
) 
select @Total_Claims_Processed = count(id)
from cte2
where benefit_code_id  not in ('739');
```

Comment: Getting an error at the first select,select @Total_new_claims_received.  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.

Comment: There was a comma left at the end of the cte. I edited.